# Is there a module to hide URL path settings by content type?

Tags: 6, path-aliases

Eg. I'd like to let the client see the URL path settings fieldset for Page but not for Slide.

I'm happy to implement it myself, just wondered if someone else already had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything out there at the moment (perhaps my search wasn't extensive enough either), but you can hide the URL path settings fieldset yourself easily with one line of code:

```
<?php $form['path']['#access'] = FALSE; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a sandbox module to automate Laxman13's answer](http://drupal.org/sandbox/andy/1289886) for fieldsets in general (including *URL path settings*).

Comment: That might be a good feature to add to the [Override Node Options](http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) module, as I don't believe it currently supports that.